# Prove that $U-f(U)$ is an open set.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, continuity

> Let $(X,d)$ be a compact metric space. Let $f:X\to X$ be continuous. Fix a point $x_0\in X$, and assume that $d(f(x),x_0)\geq 1$ whenever $x\in X$ is such that $d(x,x_0)=1$. Prove that $U\setminus f(U)$ is an open set in $X$, where $U=\{x\in X:d(x,x_0)<1\}$.

([original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sprUh.jpg))

My attempt:

I tried to get a contradiction. So I assume that there is $x\in U- f(U)$ such that for all $\epsilon >0$, $$B(x,\epsilon)\cap f(U)\neq \varnothing.$$ So $d(x,x_0)<1$ and there is $y\in B(x,\epsilon)\cap f(U)\neq \varnothing$. Hence $d(x,y)<\epsilon$ and there is $z\in U$ such that $f(z)=y$. After that I was stuck. Am I in the wrong track? Is there a different way of approaching the result? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: (MathJax / LaTeX note: the right symbols for the empty set are `\emptyset` or `\varnothing`.)

Answer (score 2):

Let $S=\{x\in X:d(x,x_0)= 1\}$. Note that $f(S)\cap U=\emptyset$ by the assumption on $f$. Therefore 
$$
U\setminus f(U)=U\setminus f(U\cup S).
$$
Now $U\cup S$ is closed, so by the closed map lemma, its image is also closed. Can you finish?

Comment: To use closed map lemma, how do we know that $X$ is Hausdorff?

Comment: $X$ is a metric space, and all metric spaces are Hausdorff

Answer (score 1):

Set $$\overline{U}=\{x|d(x,x_0)\leq1\}.$$Then $\overline{U}$ is closed in $X$ and hence compact. Since $f$ is continuous, $f(\overline{U})$ is again compact, and in particular closed. By assumption we have$$U\setminus f(U)=U\setminus f(\overline{U}),$$and we're done.